# LibGDX ShapeRenderer circle drawing

Tags: android, libgdx, draw

I have tried several solutions for drawing circles to generated coordinates.
It is not working, but I do not know what is the problem with filledCircle method? How can I replace it?

Message:

> FilledCircle cannot be resolved or is not a field

Code:

```
package com.example.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;

public class MainClass extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
OrthographicCamera camera;
ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
private Sprite sprite;     

@Override
public void create () {
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void render () {

     Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
     Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
     Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(sprite, 200, 200, 64, 64);
      shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
      shapeRenderer.filledCircle(50, 50, 32);
      shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      shapeRenderer.end();
      batch.end();  
}


}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The method `begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType type)` accepts a `ShapeType`. There are 3 [Shapetypes](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.html): Filled, Line and Point. There is no `FilledCircle` like you are using (that's what the error message says to you).

So, you should use `shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);`

Also, there is not `filledCircle()` method. Try `shapeRenderer.circle(50, 50, 32);`.

**EDIT**:

This is your code without some of the mistakes. You'll need to understand it and complete some parts, copy-paste won't do it.

```
@Override
public void create () {
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(300, 480); //FILL THE VALUES HERE
    sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg")));  //FILL THE VALUES HERE

     sprite.setBounds(200, 200, 64, 64);
}


@Override
public void render () {

     Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
     Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
     Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

      batch.begin();  
      sprite.draw(batch);  
      batch.end();

      shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
      shapeRenderer.circle(50, 50, 32);
      shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

Comment: Note that there *used* to be "filledCircle" methods and types.  One of the pre-1.0.0 cleanups removed a lot of redundancy from the `ShapeRenderer` class.  There are probably other SO answers that still refer to the old API.

Comment: It is seemly okay, but now there is a NullPointer exception at line 36. Is there a problem with batch? What should be the problem?

Comment: Batch is ok, the problem is your camera. It's null because you never initialized it. For example, on the `onCreate()`: `camera = new OrthographicCamera()`.

Comment: Okay, I have fixed, thanks, but there is also same error in line 40.
This: batch.draw(....)

Comment: I'll edit the answer with the changes you'll need. You've got many mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize a shaperenderer inside of a batch, you will stop batch (batch end) and start the shaperenderer, when you stopped the shaperenderer you can start the batch again.
Sorry for the fails, my english are no very good

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).